# How can I apply opacity when I am using cache?

Tags: javascript, filter, kineticjs, opacity

I am developing some app with kineticjs 5.1.0 and just starting with kineticjs.

This application can change the src attribute of an image, so the onLoad method will be called an unkown amount of times.

It also has sliders to control rotation, zoom, opacity and the intensity of some filters controlled with jquery.

However I have not been able to apply opacity and filtering at the same time.

At this moment, at load time (onLoad) I reset all transformation values (rotation , zoom, offset, filters and opacity).

```
leftImage.onload=function(){
    layer.add(imagenIzquierda);
    stage.add(layer);
    imagenIzquierda.cache();
    imagenIzquierda.filters([Kinetic.Filters.Brighten]);
    anchoIzquierdo=this.naturalWidth;
    altoIzquierdo=this.naturalHeight;
    escalaIzquierda=200/altoIzquierdo;
    $("#zoomIzquierdo").slider("option", "value", escalaIzquierda*100);
    $("#opacidadIzquierda").slider("option","value",100);
    $("#rotacionIzquierda").slider("option", "value", 0);
    imagenIzquierda.position({x: anchoIzquierdo/2*escalaIzquierda, 
                              y:altoIzquierdo/2*escalaIzquierda});
    imagenIzquierda.offset({x: anchoIzquierdo/2, y: altoIzquierdo/2});
    imagenIzquierda.scale({x: escalaIzquierda, y: escalaIzquierda});
    imagenIzquierda.rotation(0);
    imagenIzquierda.opacity(1);
    layer.draw();
};
```

And on the sliders slide event I simple set the values, like this

```
                $("#opacidadIzquierda").on("slide", function(event, ui){
                imagenIzquierda.opacity(ui.value/100);
                stage.draw();
            });
```

My observatios are that opacity has no effect if there is a cache, but I cannot apply filters if there isn't one. 
How should I go about it?

EDIT:

After much googling I came up with https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/847, and a closer look at the Release Schedule tells me than indeed "opacity doesn't affect cached shapes https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/847 "

What I am doint is clearing cache, saving/reseting offset, rotation and scale, applying opacity, caching, and reappling old offset, rotation and scale and filters.
The result is that now changing opacity is slow, as those calculations take place while the slider moves so as to get a 'live view'.

Comment: Caching makes objects really stiff. I had to go through the same tricks as you, that works, but this is not really nice... However I think there is no smarter solution for the time being.